# gksu replacement

Tags: centos, polkit, gksu, pkexec

In the old days of CentOS 5, I had an application that ran as another user. 
I created a .desktop file which ran a command that looked like this:

```
gksu -u anotheruser someapplication
```

When the user clicked the icon,
a popup asked for the password of "anotheruser". 
When the password was correct, "someapplication" started.

Now in the modern days of CentOS 7,
I can't find a replacement for this behaviour. 
I tried beesu:

```
beesu -l -P someapplication anotheruser
```

but it is asking me for the root password instead of "anotheruser" password.

I also tried pkexec:

```
pkexec --user anotheruser someapplication
```

with the same result.

Both methods also have problems finding the correct display variable:

```
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have seen this question, but i still have the first part of the problem. How to run as nonroot user without typing the root password. I don't want to give the root password to the user.

Comment: Further explanation: Let's say i have 3 users on the machine: user1, user2 and root. I want that user1 has the possibility to run an application as user2. When he clicks the icon user1 should be asked for the password of user2 and not the password of user1 or root.

Comment: Now i found kdesu which for now seems to be a drop-in replacment for gksu

Comment: Try pkexec which will promote you native polkit agent to authenticate

Answer (score 0):

Try using sudo with an alternate user and root password in a terminal:

`sudo -u USER COMMAND`

If the display works correctly, you can setup sudo (in the sudoers file via `visudo`) to use the target user's password:

**targetpw**
If set, sudo will prompt for the password of the user specified by the -u option (defaults to root) instead of the password of the invoking user when running a command or editing a file.

From there just build the command to launch with in an xterm.

I just remembered, I used `gksudo` briefly when first trying Ubuntu, is that maybe what you are thinking of?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not going to help. The key point is that `gksu` will present a graphical password dialog, whereas `su`/`sudo` will want to read the password from the console, which is unavailable in the desktop-launcher scenario described here. Also, `gksudo` is basically part of the same software package, so if one isn't available, neither is the other.

Comment: @AdminBee I believe you could use `visudo` to configure passwordless usage for a specific user/binary combination. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password

Comment: Also just realized that in the original answer I also mentioned to wrap launch in an xterm, therefore allowing the password to be typed.

Comment: ....also you'll need additional mojo to copy the Xauthority data unless you do something dumb like `xhost +localhost`